# Round Robin Query Reply

Tags: networking, server, indicator, netplan, multi-core

Hi Dear i set multipe ips on ubuntu 18 in netplan i want send any network dns qury on ubuntu by round robin protocol multiple ip

first query by ip 1
second query by ip 2
third query by ip 3

How do this???

Comment: Ubuntu 18?  There is no such release; do you mean Ubuntu Core 18?  If you mean Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, it's EOSS this month, with it already dropped from https://packages.ubuntu.com/ as its 5 years of *standard* support ended in April 2023 (5 years after release in April 2018), thus ability to provide help isn't easy. Ubuntu Core 18 also becomes off-topic *end of May 2023* on this site too.